# How to use sed with variables, quotes, forward slashes and backticks in a perl script?

Tags: bash, perl, sed

I have this path /home/myname/dir1/dir2/case_33 stored as

`my $pathtowdir = pwd`

I stored case_33 as

`my $foldername = 'basename pwd'`

Then I have this command

`system("sed -i 's+case_.*/+$foldername/+g' file.mcr");`

file.mcr contains a line that says

/home/myname/dir1/dir2/case_55/anotherfile.dat

I need "case_55" to be replaced with "case_33". I was expecting the above command to do that. I assumed "case_.*/" which is equivalent to "case_55/" from the file and replace with "$foldername/" which is equivalent to "case_33/".However, that didn't happen. The "case_55" remained. Any help on what I am missing is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pwd` is not a Perl function. `'basename pwd'` doesn't run the command, it's just a string.

There's usually no need to call sed from Perl, as Perl can do the substitution itself. Running a new shell might be slower than doing everything from within Perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.014; # /r

use Cwd qw{ getcwd };
use File::Basename qw{ basename };

my $pathtowdir = getcwd();
my $foldername = basename($pathtowdir);

open my $mcr, '<', 'file.mcr' or die $!;
open my $out, '>', 'file.mcr.new' or die $!;
print {$out} s{case_.*/}{$foldername/}gr while <$mcr>;
close $out;
rename 'file.mcr.new', 'file.mcr' or die $!;
```

If you can install modules from CPAN, I'd recommend [Path::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Path::Tiny) which you can use instead of [Cwd](http://p3rl.org/Cwd) and [File::Basename](http://p3rl.org/File::Basename).

Comment: There's also the core `Cwd` and `File::Basename` modules if OP doesn't want to install additional modules.

Comment: One of these days I'll have to give in and come around to the using `Path::Tiny` for everything side.